# How to create a FTP Server for a Ticketing Desktop application using python and Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, file-upload, download, fileserver

I have created a basic ticketing system that allows user to login and create view and update tickets. I created it with Python and Tkinter for the GUI.

I would like to add a feature that allows a user to upload a file (image, PDF excel etc.) when creating a ticket. To do this I understand I would need to create a File Server. But I am not sure where to start or what technology to use? I have done some research and come up with some general questions

1. Should the File server be hosted on a webserver i.e. http posts and gets for upload download
2. Can you create a local machine file server then use socket programing too upload/download the files?
3. Is their any tutorials on uploading/downloading files to a remote machine using its public IP address and port number?

Any advice or places to start would be greatly appreciated. This is my first large coding project so I am pretty new to all of this.

Thank you.

Comment: You could avoid this "FTP" and then go for convert image into base64 and then storing it in a mysql database(as blob?) and then reading the image back.

Comment: I think it is better to create a web application instead of local GUI application because all the tickets information and login credentials are to be stored and retrieved from a remote machine.